# Usage of send and send_to when using boost::asio::ip::udp

Tags: c++, linux, sockets, udp, boost-asio

In `boost::asio` documentation, as far as I could understand, `send` is used to send data to a connected socket while `send_to` is used to send data to unconnected socket. I using the command `nc -u -l 12345` to listen to udp traffic on one computer and I try to send some text data from another computer. I took the example code of [blocking udp echo client](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/cpp11/echo/blocking_udp_echo_client.cpp). This example uses `send_to` method (for unconnected sockets), I would like to rewrite it so it will use the `send` method (for connected sockets), how do I do this? How can I make my udp socket connected? I used `bind` with my socket and it returned no error but my socket is still not connected. Is there an indication I can get from the system that my socket is connected (i.e. `netstat` or something like that)

Comment: UDP sockets are not connected, you'll need to use TCP sockets instead.

Comment: But `send` is part of the API the udp sockets expose, see [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/ip__udp/socket.html)

Comment: Don't know why this exists but you're right, I think you need to connect the socket using the connect method: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_datagram_socket/connect.html, but this still won't be a real connection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UDP "connected" term is not the same as TCP. You will not see UDP "connections" in `netstat` output.

As **[man 7 udp](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/udp.7.html)** says:

> When connect(2) is called on the socket, the default destination
>   address is set and datagrams can now be sent using send(2) or write(2)
>   without specifying a destination address.

So, you can do `connect` on `boost::asio::ip::udp::socket` and later use `send` method without specifying endpoint. Check out [udp::socket](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/ip__udp/socket.html) manual for methods you need.

Comment: You are right, I used `bind` by mistake when I should have used `connect`